# Laravel joins using different database query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am constructing this query in my Laravel controller;

```
$payments = DB::table('payments')->leftJoin('postcodes.201502_postcode', 'payments.Vendor ZIP', '=', '201502_postcode.postcode');

    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $payments = $payments->leftJoin('postcodes.pc_'.$key, '201502_postcode.'.$key, '=', 'pc_'.$key.'', 'code');
    }

    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $payments = $payments->orWhereIn('pc_'.$key.'.code', $input[$key]);
    }

    $payments = $payments->select('Vendor ZIP' ,  'Input RAC' ,  'Input LPC Code' ,  'Input UIN Code')->get();
```

An example `$input` looks like this;

```
Array
(
[county] => Array
    (
        [0] => E10000003
        [1] => E10000006
    )

[locauth] => Array
    (
        [0] => E07000223
        [1] => E07000032
    )

[parlc] => Array
    (
        [0] => W07000058
        [1] => S14000003
    )
```

)

There are 5 fields in total. Not all five fields are required though. Above, "the User" is only searching on 3 for example.

The error I get is `Unknown column 'pc_county' in 'on clause'`. I'm not sure where to put my dots. Can I escape the dots?

It's getting confusing because the `201502_postcode` table is in the `postcodes` database... and that table has a `postcode` field. The `pc_xxxxx` tables are also in this same `postcodes` database.

This is in a separate db to the `payments` table.

Comment: You are trying to join tables on different databases? Also why are there column names with spaces in them `Vendor ZIP`?

Comment: Yes. that's exactly it! The lookup tables are in a different database. And it's not my data. It's my customers. They want the spaces.